# Is there any way to use atof and determine if the value changed is an actual 0 or there was an erroneous value?

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out a way to use atof() in order to create a simple vector calculator, but the only issue I have is inputting the elements of the vectors. Using atof, since the return value is 0 if the character doesn't convert. Is there anyway to check if the value inputted by the user from fgets into a character array is 0, before it passes to atof?

Here's my code so far for checking the character:

```
do
{
    printf("%s", promptMessage);
    fgets(size, 256, stdin);
    /*if(size == 0)
    {
        myInput = atof(size);
        sucessful = true;
    }*/
    if(atof(size) != 0)
    {

        myInput = atof(size);
        sucessful = true;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Please enter a correct number: ");
    }
}while(!sucessful);
```

Sorry if I'm not making much sense but what I'm asking is can I check if a value from a character array is 0 before sending it to atof, or do some sort of check so I can actually set a 0 value for an entry for a vector element?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: Are you sure this is C++? If so then why would you get using `printf`, `fgets` and `atof`?

Comment: Check the characters in the string to see if they contain only digits and up to one period.

Comment: Why don't you just use `scanf`?

Comment: It's procedural c++, as according to my prof. And would using sscanf be better to use?

Comment: The standard doesn't define any error reporting other than 0.0 (which, too, is a valid value). However, if you use MSVCRT and don't care about portability, you're in luck -- it sets errno to EINVAL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `atof()`: `atof()` doesn't have a useful error indication. Use `strtod()` instead.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure if we're allowed to use strtod() but is it possible to do this with sscanf()?

Comment: `strtod()` is a lower-level function than `atof()` as `atof()` just calls `strtod()` (well, at least, it could). Yes, you can use `sscanf()`, too: `if (sscanf("%lf", &value) == 1)`, if `value` is of type `double` or `"%f"` if `value` is of type `float`, I think (I'm never sure about the format specifiers for the `<stdio.h>` functions; I'm more knowledgeable about C++ IOstreams...).

Comment: That sscanf value helped a bunch! I was trying to see if (..&value) == 0 but it wasn't working, but now everything seems to be good! Thanks a lot!

Comment: A problem with `sscanf` is that it has *undefined behavior* if the input string is syntactically a number, but is outside the range of the target type. `strtod` is the only way to avoid that problem (unless you implement it yourself from scratch).

Comment: @KeithThompson: I realize that 7.21.6.2 paragraph 10 says that the behavior is undefined if the value is outside the target range but it seems IEEE 754 binary floating points cover the entire range, including the infinities! The fact that the behavior is undefined would make most format specifiers entirely useless! (not that I would mind much - another argument in favor of C++ IOStreams)

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Neither C nor C++ requires IEEE 754. And the phrasing in the C standard is "If this object does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined."; I don't *think* IEEE infinity necessarily avoids undefined behavior for something like `sscanf("1.0e99999", "%lf", &x)`.

Answer (score -1):

Usually easiest solutions are hard to spot:

```
if ( memcmp(buffer,"0.0\n",4) == 0 )
{
    // zero - can call atof
}
else
{
    // whatever
}
```

Of course it may be your requirement that zero is actually represented this way and not with any other pattern. After all sane people write 0.0 not -0.000 etc ;-)